# Hibernate - update query with where in clause

Tags: hibernate, sql-update

I'll start with a heads-up warning that I'm a hibernate rookie.
Let's say I've got a query like that:

```
UPDATE entity SET attribute='value' WHERE anotherAttribute IN (val1, val2);
```

What is the correct way to execute such query if my project uses hibernate?
Do I go with simple createSQLQuery()? I'd like to do it in a more "object-oriented" way but I seem to have a problem with getting data from existing database and updating it. Do I use createQuery() and get the data to update and then go thought the result list and use setters? Another problem is the where in clause...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "object-oriented" way supported by Hibernate is via criteria API but it doesn't support updates, only selects. You would need to iterate through it and call the setter to update (which is fine for small collections and works well with level-2 cache but a disaster is your dataset is large). Otherwise use HQL or native SQL.

Hibernate criteria query:

```
 session.createCriteria(Entity.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("attribute", "value"))
    .add(Restrictions.in("anotherAttribute", <collection-of-values>)
    .list();
```

Another option worth exploring is [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com).

Comment: I did this a bit different at the end. Because there was a lack of any other responses I guess checkmark goes to you. Thanks.